# Fixing a "not an editor command" error

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I've toying with someone else's `.vimrc` file. I'm getting an error on a function call within the `.vimrc` file.

```
Error detected while processing <FILE>:
line 1500:
E492: Not an editor command: EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
line 1501:
E492: Not an editor command: EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

Lines 1500 and 1501 are as follows:

```
EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

There is a plugin in  `~/.vim/plugin` directory that accompanied this `.vimrc` configuration that has the following function in it:

```
function EQAS_Align (mode, ...) range
  let option = a:0 ? a:1 : {}

  <snip>

endfunction
```

I'm not sure what the problem is and I don't know enough about VIM scripting to fix this.

**EDIT**

This line is in the `.vimrc` file before these functions are called: `runtime plugin/eqalignsimple.vim`

Comment: May I ask why there is an action that seems to modify the current buffer in your .vimrc ? You'd better extract these `:call` to `EQAS_Align` to another function or to a _macros_ file. This way the action will be executed only when you explicitly request so.

Comment: I have no idea. It's someone else's vim file I'm studying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the following 2 lines:

```
EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

... refer to a custom function named `EQAS_Align()`.

It depends on what you want to do with it, but if you want its code to be processed, you have to prefix its name with the `:call` command:

```
call EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
call EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

To read its return value, you can use the `:echo` command:

```
echo EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
echo EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

To assign its value to a variable, you can use the `:let` command:

```
let your_var1 = EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
let your_var2 = EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

To bind it to some keys in normal mode, you can use the `:nnoremap` command:

```
nnoremap <key1> :call EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')<CR>
nnoremap <key2> :call EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')<CR>
```

To bind it to a custom command, you can use the `:command` command:

```
command! YourCommand1 call EQAS_Align('\S:',         '',   '\s')
command! YourCommand2 call EQAS_Align('[[:punct:]]', '',   '\s')
```

---

Regarding the function itself:

```
function EQAS_Align (mode, ...) range
  let option = a:0 ? a:1 : {}

  <snip>

endfunction
```

You probably want to add a bang after the `function` keyword, otherwise Vim will complain each time you re-source your `vimrc` because it won't be able to overwrite the old definition:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:
line XXX:
E122: Function EQAS_Align already exists, add ! to replace it
```

---

The function is defined with the `range` attribute, which means that if you pass a range to the `:call` command, the function will be called only once. Which probably means that it will handle the range itself, using the variables `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` (see `:h :func-range`).

After the named argument `mode`, it accepts the argument `...`, which means that you could pass up to 20 more optional arguments. If there are optional arguments, inside the function, you can access them with the variables `a:1`, `a:2`, and so on; or with the list `a:000`.
`a:0` is the number of optional arguments (see `:h a:0`).

---

The line:

```
let option = a:0 ? a:1 : {}
```

… is an assignment which uses a conditional expression (see `:h expr1`).
The expression tests whether `a:0` is different than `0`. If it is, then the variable `option` is assigned the value `a:1`, otherwise the value `{}`.
It means that if there are optional arguments, then the value of `option` should be the first optional argument, otherwise it should be an empty dictionary.

You could probably do something similar using the `get()` function:

```
let option = get(a:, '1', {})
```

… which means: take the dictionary `a:` (which contains all the arguments of the function), and look for the key `1` (first argument of the function). If you find the key, then return its associated value. If you don't find it, then return `{}`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, the issue was no `call` in front of the function. Unfortunately, the plugin throws a bunch of other errors that complain about bad arguments. A problem for another day.

Answer (score 3):

Based on `:help startup`, `vimrc` files (section 3) are loaded before plugins (section 4), so it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to use plugin-defined functions in your `~/.vimrc`.

Section 4 does note that plugin loading is equivalent to `:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` You could call that in your `~/.vimrc` before the lines calling your plugin's function, or you could use a narrower command such as `:runtime! plugin/my_plugin.vim` to only load `my_plugin`.

Note that either of these may result in the plugin(s) being loaded twice; once while loading your `~/.vimrc` and once during regular plugin loading. Off the top of my head, I know that can potentially cause problems with defining autocommands twice. `:help :autocmd` provides some suggestions for how to deal with that, if your plugin uses autocommands, you may want to check and make sure it protects itself.

Comment: This line is in the `.vimrc`. I forgot to include it in my question: `runtime plugin/eqalignsimple.vim`

Comment: @StevieD Ah, in that case, [user9433424's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11404/2736) is probably your solution.